# Positioning of floating column header

Tags: php, jquery, header

This code works well apart from when the floating header appears it is one pixel to the right of the original.

Any way to line them up fully? So when you scroll the header floats smoothly and doesn't appear to move out to the right ?

```
<title>Table with Persistent Headers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Styles.css">
<style>
.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<style>
th {background-color:#FF0000;}
</style>
 <script src="js/wiz/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
 <script>
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <h1>Persistent Headers</h1>

        <p>Scroll down and watch the table headers stay with the table when they normally would be scrolled off the screen.</p>

    <table class="persist-area">
        <thead>
          <tr class="persist-header">
             <th>Column One Header</th>
             <th>Column Two Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data1</td>
             <td>table1 data1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data2</td>
             <td>table1 data2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data3</td>
             <td>table1 data3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data4</td>
             <td>table1 data4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data5</td>
             <td>table1 data5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data6</td>
             <td>table1 data6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>table1 data7</td>
             <td>table1 data7</td>
          </tr>
           </tbody>
      </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is moving to the right is because you are applying `position: fixed` to an element inside a table, and giving "*position*" to elements such as tr, td, or th isn't really a good practice as they weren't made for tables.

However in your case, it seems to work if you add a `margin-left:-1px;` to the`.floatingHeader` class.

```
.floatingHeader {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin-left: -1px; // *** This one here ***
}
```

Comment: Setting 
`margin-left: -2px; margin-top: -2px;` seems to have done it thanks :)

Comment: It seems to be fine thanks.
Just having a slight issue with the header resizing when I use dynamic content. I'll need to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `left` position fixes the problem:

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible",
            left: offset.left // <-- set left position
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });
       };
   });
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/UpAeu/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. My Jquery is 1.8.0 is that the issue ?

Comment: There might be some other issue in your code possibly. I've updated the example fiddle to use jQuery 1.8.0 and it works just fine with that as well: http://jsfiddle.net/UpAeu/1/. Also what browser are you testing in?

Comment: I'm testing in chrome and IE

Comment: Haven't tested in IE as I'm on an Ubuntu machine, but it works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox